# Não perder o texto de input ao trocar de página

Tags: html, input

Bom dia, estou precisando fazer o seguint: O usuário digita algum texto num input e esse texto não se perde se ele trocar de página. Esse input não tem nenhum botão de submit. Como posso fazer isso? Tem como fazer sem uso de BD?

Comment: você tem que ter algo que relacione as duas páginas, se você usa php você pode gravar em uma $_SESSION se você tem um arquivo js que esta vinculado as duas páginas pode colocar em uma váriavel global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode gravar o valor do input em uma variável e depois resgatar ela com algum evento como `onchange`, `onclick` e etc.

Exemplo funcional:

```
<html>  

<head>  
    <title>Teste</title>  
</head>  



<body>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
function mostrarValor(){  
    var frm = document.frm;  
    var val1 = frm.valor1.value;  

    alert(val1 );  

}  
</script>  


<form name="frm">  

<input type="text" name="valor1"  size="10" >  

<button type="button" onclick="mostrarValor();">Veja os valores</button>
</form>  
</body>  

</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado :D Ajudou bastante

Comment: @RicardoAfonso Sempre as ordens!

Answer (score 1):

Podes utilizar jQuery para ler o texto escrito nesse input:
Javascript:

```
 $("#teu_input_id").keyup(function(){
    var input = $(this).val();

    $.post("/backend.php", {"input": input});
});
```

PHP:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['input'] = filter_var($_POST['input'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Nas páginas onde não queres perder a informação:
PHP

```
session_start();
$input = filter_var($_SESSION['input'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="teu_input" id="teu_input_id" value="<?=$_SESSION['input']" />
```